# for loop with both filters offset and limit (Liquid / Shopify)

Tags: liquid

Is there a way to make a for loop with both filters offset and limit in the same tag?

I am making a website in shopify using their language Liquid

The tag i want is:

```
{%- for variant in product.variants offset: 11, limit: 21  -%}
// display cards
{%- endfor -%}
```

However, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
{%- for variant in product.variants offset:11 limit:21  -%}
// display cards
{%- endfor -%}
```